# Makefile Compilation using Automatic Variables

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying simple thing in makefile but unable to make it work. Following is the example file which is related to my requirement:

### Makefile:

```
OBJDIR=obj

dummy_build_folder := $(shell mkdir -p $(OBJDIR))

CC = gcc

SRCS =  1/print.c \
        2/add.c

INCLUDE =   -I "./1/" \
          -I "./2/" \

OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
  @-if not exist $(OBJDIR) mkdir $(OBJDIR) 1>NUL 2>NUL  
  $(CC) -c $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

all: $(OBJS)
  @-if not exist $(OBJDIR) mkdir $(OBJDIR) 1>NUL 2>NUL
  @echo $(OBJS)

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    rm $(OBJS)
```

---

When I'm trying to run the same I'm getting following error:
"make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/print.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop."

I tried of using "$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCS)" also, but here $< is pointing only to  print.c, whereas $@ is incrementing to next file (i.e. print.o & add.o). Above is trying to compiling the print.c file twice and placing the output in both print.o and add.o

```
gcc -c -I "./1/" -I "./2/"  1/print.c -o obj/print.o

gcc -c -I "./1/" -I "./2/"  1/print.c -o obj/add.o
```

---

My Directory structure is:

```
RootFolder:

    1/print.c

    2/add.c

    3/xyz.c (Don't want to compile this file)

    Makefile
```

---

Also, I want to keep all the .o files in a different folder (./obj/*o) in above location.

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no dependencies between `.o` files and the corresponding `.c` files and no matching rules, this is what `make` tells you by `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/print.o', needed by 'all'. Stop.`.

The pattern rule `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c` cannot match a `.c` to `.o` because the object files do not have the directory level present in the paths to `.c`. That directory level is removed by that `$(notdir ...)` call.

The `%` (the stem) parts in the pattern rule must match. E.g. in `$(OBJDIR)/1/print.o : 1/print.c` the stem is `1/print`. Whereas in `$(OBJDIR)/print.o : 1/print.c` `print` does not match `1/print`.

A good way to avoid this problem is to build the same directory structure for the output files as that of the source files.

Fixed `Makefile`:

```
OBJDIR := obj
CC := gcc

SRCS := 1/print.c 2/add.c

INCLUDE := -I "./1/" -I "./2/"

OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,${OBJDIR}/%.o,${SRCS})
DEPS := $(patsubst %.c,${OBJDIR}/%.d,${SRCS})

all: $(OBJS)
    @echo "Object files are $(OBJS)"

.SECONDEXPANSION:

# This rule creates the object file and its directory.
$(OBJS) : ${OBJDIR}/%.o : %.c | $$(dir $$@)
    $(CC) -c $(INCLUDE) $< -MD -MP -o $@

${OBJDIR}/%.d : ;

${OBJDIR}/% :
    mkdir -p $@

clean :
    rm -rf ${OBJDIR}

.PHONY: all clean

-include ${DEPS}
```

Example usage:

```
$ mkdir 1 2
$ touch 1/print.c 2/add.c
$ make
mkdir -p obj/1/
gcc -c -I "./1/" -I "./2/" 1/print.c -MD -MP -o obj/1/print.o
mkdir -p obj/2/
gcc -c -I "./1/" -I "./2/" 2/add.c -MD -MP -o obj/2/add.o
Object files are obj/1/print.o obj/2/add.o
```

Notes:

1. The output directories get created automatically for you using the order-only dependencies `| $$(dir $$@)`.
2. Header file dependencies get created automatically for you using `-MD -MP` and `-include ${DEPS}` bits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and the provided solution is working for me. Just for curiosity, can we do it in any other way, I mean without using .SECONDEXPANSION ? Also can you please explain the meaning of | symbol here "| $$(dir $$@)" , I got the context that we are trying to pass the directory path and searching for all .c file in that directory.

Comment: @Dipanshu `| $$(dir $$@)` means the target file `$$@` depends on its directory `$$(dir ...`). As order only dependency `|`, that is, the directory must exists, but ignore its timestamp.

Comment: @Dipanshu see [order-only-prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-order_002donly-prerequisites) and [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).

Comment: @Dipanshu Without `.SECONDEXPANSION` `make` cannot automatically add the dependency on the directory and automatically create it.